# I'm on a 12-hour blow -- meaning of "blow"?

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang

Example:

> — I need you back in 4 instead of 12. I got half of Korea coming in at noon.
>   — No, no, no, I'm on **a 12-hour blow**. Call Tedesco.

What does **a 12-hour blow** mean?

Comment: Just guessing --  down-time after a previous shift of work|on-duty.

Comment: Can you please add a source for the quotation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Blow** here is a slang usage (originally, U.S.) meaning a **break** (from work, particularly, *physical* work).

Compare to [*take a **breather***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/breather) = *a pause, as for breath*, and [***blow***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blow.%20drug) = *cocaine or other "recreational" drugs*, and [*stop for a **puff***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stop%20for%20a%20puff%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) = *have a cigarette break.*

I confess that after several minutes checking online, I can't be sure which of the above represents the *origin* of the usage, but it puts me in mind of a whale surfacing for breath (through its [*blowhole*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blowhole)), so I'd go with the *blow = breather* route. Nevertheless, I'm sure many people say *"I'm going for a blow"*, when they're thinking in terms of *having a "smoke break"*, rather than a chance to *catch their breath*.

---

Personally, I find OP's cited usage slightly "odd", because to me a "blow" is a relatively *short* break. But I'm a BrE speaker - perhaps either AmE speakers are okay with using it for longer periods of being "off duty", or *in the specific context*, the speaker thinks of 12 hours as a relatively short period of free time (perhaps he's a soldier, offshore oil-rigger, etc., who's normally "at work" for weeks at a time, punctuated by periods of several days' leave of absence).

Comment: It sounds pretty odd to me too (US).

Comment: Reading over the [War of the Worlds (2005)](http://www.allreadable.com/655d6VPC) narrative, there is a reference to union regulations later on. I think the additional context changes the meaning a bit. Certain union regulations require a specific length of time off after working a certain number of hours and it may be the slang was appropriated to mean that specific type of enforced break. I'm not really familiar with it either.

Comment: +1 As native Br E I would have completely misinterpreted the sentence. Blow as a rest break is something I've never come across, ever. I would have mistakenly assumed he was abbreviating 'blow out' & was either drinking, eating, or both, to excess. Two nations divided by one language ;-)

Answer (score 2):

From Wiktionary:

> **Blow** - [noun sense 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow#Noun) - (informal) A chance to catch one’s breath.
>   *The players were able to get a **blow** during the last timeout.*

The word seems to be often used in this sense in sporting contexts.

From another source, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*:

> **blow**, sense 4, "a breathing space"..
>   ..**[get a blow](http://books.google.ru/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&lpg=PA99&dq=rest%20%22get%20a%20blow%22&hl=ru&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q=rest%20%22get%20a%20blow%22&f=false)**, to get a breath of fresh air, or a considerable exposure to wind: from ca. 1890

Comment: So, what's the meaning? The gay has 12 hours of tree time before he has to go back to work?

Comment: @CookieMonster -  Yes, the *guy* was taking a 12-hour rest, a *breath of fresh air*, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

It means to take a break (short).  You might say, "I need to take a quick blow."

It would absolutely not make sense to say that sentence.  A 12 hour blow would only be used in a porn film.  The word blow has drug and sex connotations and generally would never and should never be used like that unless you are doing an inside joke.